# Is there a way too insert a parameter into a sql avg query?

Tags: java, android-room

I would like to do some like that :

```
SELECT AVG(:MYPARAMETER) FROM TABLE WHERE someconditions
```

I use Room database with Android Studio and i have this:

```
 @Query("SELECT AVG(:type) as average FROM REPORTS WHERE DATA LIKE :data" )
public double avgValue(String type,String data);
```

But it doesn't work.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is your table name un capitals?, as far as I understand queries are case sensitive.